# What's the default BasedOnStyle value for clang-format?

Tags: clang-format

Does the ClangFormat `BasedOnStyle` style option have a default value that's applied if one's not selected by the user, and if so, what is that default value?

According to the *BasedOnStyle* option section of the [CLANG-FORMAT STYLE OPTIONS](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) documentation for Clang 12, `BasedOnStyle` is a configurable format style option that can be one of `LLVM`, `Google`, `Chromium`, `Mozilla`, `WebKit`, `Microsoft`, or `GNU`. There's no mention in that section however of whether `BasedOnStyle` even has a default value.

I searched online for documentation to answer this but didn't find any. Scanning through all of the `clang-format` tagged questions on SO for uses of `BasedOnStyle` also revealed no answers. Given that ClangFormat is from the LLVM project it'd be unsurprising that this option defaults to `LLVM` but that assumes that this option has a default which seems unclear to begin with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seeing as there didn't seem to be Q&A already on SO for this and guessing others have also wondered about this or will wonder about this, I thought I'd post the question, and the answer I eventually found (regrettably only after checking the source code)...

In the comments in the [`clang/include/clang/Format/Format.h`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/clang/include/clang/Format/Format.h#L1967) file, and also in the `RawStringFormats` section of the [`clang/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.rst`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/clang/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.rst) file, is the following sentence:

> If 'BasedOnStyle' is not found, the formatting is based on llvm style.

That led me back to the [CLANG-FORMAT STYLE OPTIONS](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) documentation for Clang 12 that I'd mentioned in my question, where I realized this information was all along. It just isn't in the section on `BasedOnStyle` but confusingly is in the section on `RawStringFormats`.

Additionally, testing on [clang-format-configurator](https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/), seems to corroborate that the default `BasedOnStyle` value is indeed `LLVM` and running `clang-format --dump-config | grep BasedOnStyle` shows:

> # BasedOnStyle:  LLVM

Answer (score 1):

I was also curious to figure out how it works.

Here are 2 lines of code that, in my opinion, explain everything:

```cpp
const char *DefaultFormatStyle = "file";

const char *DefaultFallbackStyle = "LLVM";
```

Source: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/clang/lib/Format/Format.cpp#L2942-L2944

Those values are used in `ClangFormat.cpp` file when `Style` and `FallbackStyle` variables are initialized.

Source: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/clang/tools/clang-format/ClangFormat.cpp#L62-L66

Even though the documentation states that style configuration needs to be passed explicitly via the `--style` option, the `clang-format` works when invoked directly.

```sh
# File is formatted with default configuration
# or with options from the ".clang-format` file, if present.
clang-format -i <file>
```